# Add to front method of linked list if there are no duplicate items, otherwise remove the duplicate item

Tags: java, linked-list, addition, singly-linked-list

I am having a lot of difficulty figuring out the add method of a linked list. My assignment says to:

> Implement this method, public void add(E item), inside MoveToFront
>   class. The method behaves like this: when the input does not exist in
>   the linked list, add it at the front; otherwise remove the existing
>   one from the list and reinsert it to the front.

What I have done so far is create a `contains` and `delete` method that will search for the existing item in the list and then delete it. Then it will add the item to the front of the list.

```
public int getLength() {
    Node<E> curNode = first;
    int count = 0;
    while (curNode != null) {
        curNode = curNode.next;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

public boolean Contains(E item) {
    if (first == null) {
        return false;
    }
    Node<E> currentNode = first;
    while (currentNode.next != null) {
        containCount++;
        if (currentNode.item.equals(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }
    return false;
}

public E Delete(int kth) {
    if (kth <= getLength()) {
        Node<E> currentNode = first;
        for (int i = 1; i < kth; i++) {
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }
        currentNode.next = currentNode.next.next;
        return currentNode.item;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public void add(E item) {

    if (!Contains(item)) {
        Node<E> myNode = new Node<E>(item, null);
        first = myNode;
    } else {
        Delete(containCount);
        Node<E> myNode = new Node<E>(item, null);
        first = myNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't say what exactly your problem is.  What doesn't work about the code you show us?

Answer (score 0):

I think you aren't properly linking the nodes.  Before you set the node you're inserting as the `first` node, set the node's `next` to the old `first`, like this:

```
myNode.next = first;
first = myNode;
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1. Instead of going through the list twice to first check if it contains the item, then to find and delete it, you can rewrite delete() to just go through the list and delete if a matching item is found. You can then call this method at the beginning of your add() method.
2. You should keep track of the size of the list with a simple instance variable that is updated whenever an item is added or removed, and then just let getLength() return this. Going through the whole list each time is way too expensive.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I see a getLength() method in your code. It is a linked list, if you are trying to get the length of it for this problem then you didn't get the data structure.

Now if we get to implementation I see from the requirement you have to add new element to the front one way or another. This is how I will do that-

1. Create a node and link its next to the first element of current list. This will be add method.you can do this method in the end too, it will not make much difference.
2. Then start searching for element in the list and if you find a match delete it. Make sure you don't match with the element you just added int the front.